# A word for a protecting / protected piece in chess?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Playing chess, how would you call a piece that protects another one?
Maybe a guard?
And how would you call the piece that is protected?

I need a single word for programming a ches computer.

Comment: In chess, protecting a field or a piece is called "covering", so maybe you could say that the "coverer" covers the "covered"?

Answer (score 6):

A **defender** is a piece that is protecting another piece, the **defended piece**.

> from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_tactic) - "A piece is said to defend (or protect) a piece of the defender's color if, in case the **defended piece** were taken by the opponent, the **defender** could immediately recapture.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there one single word for the defended piece? Like "ward", but better matching?

Comment: @Duke if you need a single word, based on Centaurus's answer I'd say "defendee".

Answer (score 0):

Centaurus' answer is correct (+1); I just want to highlight a special case. A [passed pawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn_(chess)#Passed_pawn) which is defended by another pawn is called a *protected passed pawn*.